# EOF Error for loading BSON in Julia in Colab

Tags: file-io, julia, google-colaboratory, eof, bson

I have been running Julia 1.7.2 on my computer using Pluto.

Using the `BSON` library in Julia, I have been able load a file with the code `BSON.load("filename.bson")`

I am now trying to create a version of this code to run in colab for my collaborators. I am able to run Julia 1.7.2 by mimicking the code at [this notebook.](https://colab.research.google.com/github/ageron/julia_notebooks/blob/master/Julia_for_Pythonistas.ipynb)

However, now when I try to run `BSON.load("filename.bson")` in colab, I get the following error:

```
EOFError: read end of file

Stacktrace:
  [1] read(s::IOStream, #unused#::Type{UInt8})
    @ Base ./iostream.jl:399
  [2] read
    @ ./Enums.jl:22 [inlined]
  [3] parse_doc(io::IOStream)
    @ BSON ~/.julia/packages/BSON/rOaki/src/read.jl:51
  [4] parse_tag(io::IOStream, tag::BSON.BSONType)
    @ BSON ~/.julia/packages/BSON/rOaki/src/read.jl:15
  [5] parse_doc(io::IOStream)
    @ BSON ~/.julia/packages/BSON/rOaki/src/read.jl:53
  [6] parse
    @ ~/.julia/packages/BSON/rOaki/src/read.jl:105 [inlined]
  [7] open(f::typeof(BSON.parse), args::String; kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Base ./io.jl:330
  [8] open
    @ ./io.jl:328 [inlined]
  [9] parse
    @ ~/.julia/packages/BSON/rOaki/src/read.jl:106 [inlined]
 [10] load (repeats 2 times)
    @ ~/.julia/packages/BSON/rOaki/src/read.jl:108 [inlined]
 [11] top-level scope
    @ In[6]:1
 [12] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [13] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1196
```

Does anyone know why the Julia code would fail in colab but not in Pluto, or what I should try to do differently?

Comment: The issue appears to have been that I was uploading the file manually instead of mounting the drive! I'm not sure why this distinction matter, but when I mount the drive I don't have this problem!